# Python - single variable built string, from multiple other variables for SMTP

Tags: python

me again, with another Python question.

I have a variable that is pieced together from a template in the config file.

This is the format that the config.ini file prepares the variable for sending:

```
template =#${var1} ${var2}: ${var3}
```

I set each of the variables in the python code as such:

```
templateArgs = dict()
    flight = a.flight or a.hex
    flight = flight.replace(" ", "")
    templateArgs['var1'] = aircraftdata.plane(a.hex)
    templateArgs['var2'] = aircraftdata.oper(a.hex)
    templateArgs['var3'] = "%.1f" % a.distance
```

It is prepared for Twitter, but Im removing that part, but sending the tweet content in the email for someone to review before posting.

This is where it is combined:

```
tweet = Template(parser.get('tweet', 'tweet_template')).substitute(templateArgs)
```

Its an SMTP email thats being sent with the data, but Ive got all that part sorted, Im just trying to make it look better. Its a hashtag string for twitter, but Im only using it in an email.

SMTP Email includes like this:

```
<p>Tweet: """ + tweet + """</p>
```

Id like, and this is the question for you, how ... in the ini file can I put in a line break so that when the email comes through each of the vars come through on a new line.

Its all working perfectly, its honestly just the new line I want to introduce. All the rest is working fine.

Im perplexed, and working from someone elses code, and a bit lost.

Sorry for the long question...just trying make sure you geniuses have enough info.

Any helpers?

Cheers
Simon

Comment: I'm a bit confused - do you need to specify a template (including linebreaks) in advance, then populate it… bit like a mailmerge?

Comment: In an ini file, you can have line breaks in the values, depending on the parser's mode, even empty lines will be included in the read values. https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure